# How to load RDB to a redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I need to load a dump.rdb file to a redis cluster instance. How to do it?

While I am keeping in data directory and trying to start the instance alone (say 11211) is flushing my rdb and new rdb file is written. Even by turning the appendonly to no.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Stop all redis instance (because redis overwrites the current rdb file when it exits).
do the below steps in master instance.
Copy your backup rdb file to the redis working directory (this is the dir option in your redis config). Also make sure your backup filename matches the dbfilename config option.
Change the redis config appendonly flag to no (otherwise redis will ignore your rdb file when it starts).
Start redis.
Run redis-cli BGREWRITEAOF to create a new appendonly file.
Restore redis config appendonly flag to yes.